# D3 sorting of horizontal bars

Tags: d3.js

I would like to reverse the data of my bar chart.  I found this code while searching but not sure how to implement.

```
dataset = dataset.sort(function(a, b) {
return a.value - b.value;
}).reverse();
```

And a snippet of my code:

```
const bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("g")

bars.append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("y", function (d) {
                return y(d.name);
            })
            .attr("height", y.bandwidth() / 2 + 10)
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("width", function (d) {
                return x(d.value) - 10;
            });
```

[On Codepen](https://codepen.io/stevechezcp5/pen/yqdROq)

Answer (score -2):

Before you use data

```
data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.value - a.value;
});
```

Comment: thank you for this, but could not get it.  do you have an example in the code?

Comment: just copy and paste just after where you define `data`. It would be good to pick up a book about Programming and Javascript in particular and start reading and practicing.